# POST запрос с body (email, pass)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Хочу сделать страницу авторизации по Email и паролю, запрос отправлять по API “Авторизация”
Нужно сделать POST запрос по url (допустим будет https://shop-shop/api/v1/disp/login), где передавать поля (email, password) хранить токет в localStorage и получать в ответ обьект

Я сделал форму где есть метод login()
Форма имеет два поля связаных через v-model.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаю как минимум два способа:

- XmlHttpRequest
- Axios

Первый способ - это для древних греков. Он уже реализован и не требует дополнительных пакетов, но громоздкий и неудобный.

Второй способ:

- Устанавливаешь axios `$ npm install axios`
- Импортируешь его `import axios from 'axios'`
- Строишь запрос, который возвращает промис.

Можно написать твой action так:

```
export function login ({ commit }, params) {
  return axios.post('url/login', params)
    .then((data) => {
      commit('setUser', data) 
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      commit('setUser', null)
    })
}
```

А можно так:

```
export async function login ({ commit }, params) {
  try {
    const data = await axios.post('url/login', params)
    commit('setUser', data)
  } catch(e) {
    commit('setUser', null)
  }
}
```

Кстати, тело запроса с `email` и `password` - это вот тот самый объект `params`. Внешний код выглядит примерно так:

```
store.dispatch('login', {
  email: this.email,
  password: this.password
})
```